# How do I use Try Except to catch a FileNotFoundError when a file is passed to a function?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that takes a filename as an argument and performs some operations on the data inside the file. I need to implement a Try Except clause that catches a FileNotFoundError (if the filename passed to the function is invalid) and returns the value 1.

Here is the function:

```
def createdict(x):
    with open (x, "r") as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        for i in range(len(lines)):
            lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip()
    return 0
```

Where would I place the Try and Except statements to catch an invalid file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def createdict(x):
    try:
        with open (x, "r") as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
            for i in range(len(lines)):
                lines[i] = lines[i].rstrip()
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return 1
    else:
        return 0
```

In this way you will only catch `FileNotFoundError`. Other exceptions will still be raised.